# Accessing a TextView from a resource file

Tags: android, textview

Let me first explain what my Androïd application is made of :
    - a class extended from an Activity. In the `OnCreate` member of my class, I try to access a TextView described in my `main.xml` file by using

```
"MyTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);".
```

- an xml file where the TextView is described as follows :
                  `<TextView
                          android:name="@+id/myTextView"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_below="@id/another TextView"/>`
In the `R.java` file, I can see that my TextView is registered.

My problem is that, when I try to get a handle on the TextView with the `findViewById` function, I get a null pointer.

It seems a mystery to me because I wrote another application where I was able to access TextViews. And I can't see any difference beetween both applications!!!

Hello,

Here is my complete layout file :

```
<TextView
    android:name="@+id/Titre"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Application GPS :"/>

<TextView
    android:name="@+id/NombreMaxSatellites"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:name="@+id/NombreSatellites"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello Android from NetBeans"/>

<TextView
    android:name="@+id/TempsAcquisition"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello Android from NetBeans"/>

<EditText
    android:name="@+id/Texte"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Le texte"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/BoutonTexte"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="130dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:text="Terminer"/>
```

I can access the `Button` but neither the `TextView` nor the `EditText`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there are some errors in the layout, due to which your changes for layout were not saved. And then it is not reflecting in R.Java. Look for any red marks in your layout. Resolve the errors before your proceed, then it should work fine. Post your complete layout file.

Comment: I have neither red lines in my layout file or compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure about 2 things

1. the ID of your textview is not repeated in the same layout
2. make sure that you are setting the content view (`setContentView()`) to the correct layout.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that any calls to `findViewById()` occur after setting the layout with `setContentView()`.

A good practice is to call `setContentView()` as the first line in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Before the finViewVyId call, I have setContentView()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is id is assigned to name `android:name="@+id/Titre"`, it should be `android:id="@+id/Titre"`.